# Generic Delegate casting

Tags: c#, generics, casting, delegates

[edit] the following works in C#

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        Func<int,string> a = intArg => "helloWorld"; // string:object
        Test(a);
        Func<int,C> b = intArg => new C(); // C:object
        Test(b);
    }
    public void Test(Func<int,object> arg){
        Console.WriteLine(arg(1).ToString());
    }
}
```

how can I achieve the same thing with self declared delegate?

```
public class C {
    public delegate Y MyDelegate<X,Y>(X input);
    public void M() {
        MyDelegate<int,string> a = intArg => "helloWorld"; // cannot convert from 'C.MyDelegate<int, string>' to 'C.MyDelegate<int, object>' 
        Test(a);
        MyDelegate<int,C> b = intArg => new C(); // cannot convert from 'C.MyDelegate<int, C>' to 'C.MyDelegate<int, object>'
        Test(b);
    }
    public void Test(MyDelegate<int,object> arg){
        Console.WriteLine(arg(1).ToString());
    }
}
```

I understand that the compiler cannot tell which type argument is for parameter (contravariance) and which is for return value (covariance), maybe there is way to specify it?

[update]
I have found my solution:
`public delegate Y MyDelegate<X,out Y>(X input);`

Comment: If you know what type you expect `Invoke` to return, cast it to that type before passing it to another method. If you don't know what you expect `Invoke` to return then there's not much you can do with the return value anyway.

Comment: in my example, I know the type is `Func<int, ? extends object>` but casting generics is not available in C#, no?

Comment: Your "upcast" example isn't what I'd call upcasting...you're actually wrapping the original delegate in a new one. And I don't see how that's a solution anyway, as you still can't call `delegateArg` like that until you cast it to an actual delegate type. Maybe you're looking for `Delegate.DynamicInvoke()`? Your "toy example" is too simple and too incomplete, rendering your question unclear.

Comment: You can attempt to cast something to a specific type - `var delegate = myObject as Func<int, string>;` You just have to know specifically what type you want to cast it to. If you know the type you can do that. But if you don't know the type then what can you do with the object anyway?

Comment: As far as the overhead of `dynamic` goes, it depends on how often the code will be called, and whether the types will change. `dynamic` adds a bit of extra overhead as compared to the normal JIT stuff that happens, but it caches the result for given types, so once you incur that overhead for a given runtime type, the overhead is minimal. Of course, anything that is called millions of times a second, you'll notice even minimal overhead.

Comment: One last note: if you're used to Java, you may recognize delegate types as essentially an interface with a single method and some syntactical sugar to simplify usage (they aren't implemented this way, but IMHO it's useful and feasible to conceptualize them that way). C# generic interface types allow type variance, so if you can convert the scenario to use interfaces instead of delegate types, you can e.g. cast `IFunc<int, ClassA>` to `IFunc<int, object>`.

Comment: `dynamic` is basically asking the compiler to compile your code without knowing if it should compile. If our code might be passing the wrong types around, we want the compiler to refuse to build it. We don't want the compiler to build it and then at runtime find out if it makes sense or not. There are no absolutes or else `dynamic` wouldn't exist. But generally we shouldn't need to use it. We should try to write code so that it knows which type is which at compile time.

Comment: @ScottHannen: Indeed, Dynamic has too high a cost. It can even affect the return type of functions it is given as parameter. As a general rule, strong Typisation is our biggest friend in the world. Dynamic is a nessesary evil when we work with weakly typed API's and what not. Without strong Typisation, we had issues like in PHP or JavaScript as handily illustrated here: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/

Comment: for the delegate I only know the parameter types, the return type is determined at runtime, which is why I want to cast it to `Func<...,...,object>` so that inside `myFunction()` I can call the delegate and spit out an object

Comment: I think I can solve my problem by a big if else check on types: `if (delegateArg.GetType() == typeof(Func<int, ClassA>)){  var castedArg = delegateArg as Func<int,ClassA>; myFunction<ClassA>(castedArg)} ` and make my function generic `void myFunction<T>(Func<int,T> arg)`, if I don't want to do a type cast, there is no other way besides using `dynamic`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call this:

```
object delegateArg = genericMethod.Invoke();
```

The return value - `delegateArg` - is a `Func<int, something>`, where `something` could be anything. And then you want to pass that `Func<int, ???>` to another method which will presumably invoke it.

You can pass that it to a method that expects `Func<int, object>` and it will compile unless the second generic argument is a value type. When you invoke it, you'll get the result of the invocation cast as an `object`. The actual type of the result will be whatever that second unknown generic argument is.

But if you don't know what that second generic argument is, then the method you pass it to isn't going to know either. The only way it could find out is by using reflection, inspecting the type, and getting the second generic argument.

So you could pass in a `Func<int, object>` and do some reflection to find out that the `object` is really a `string`. Or you could just invoke the function, get the result, and check the type of the returned value and determine that it's a `string`.

The big problem is that if you don't already know what type you're going to get, how do you know what you want to do with it? If you don't know what type `genericMethod.Invoke` is going to return with any more certainty, then how do you know you want it at all?

It's a bit like going to the store to buy a wall-mount bracket, except you don't know what it is that you want to mount on a wall. But if you don't know what it is that you want to mount, then why are you going to the store to buy a wall mount bracket?

Sometimes there are good reasons, but this is often what happens when we have functions that return something non-specific and then pass them to other methods. It's much better if we can work it out so that our code is strongly typed. We call a method that returns a certain type *because we want an object of that type.* Then we pass that thing to another method that expects that type and has a specific use for it.

There are exceptions and cases where we don't really care what the type of something is, but it's less common because we don't usually write code that isn't meant to do something specific with something specific. Unless we're certain that we really don't care what the actual type is, it's good to revisit our approach and find a way to make it strongly typed. That can involve using generics or in some cases writing more classes or methods instead of one that handles a variety of inputs.

Comment: you cannot pass a delegate `Func<int,string>` as an argument to a function expecting `Func<int,object>`, it will not compile

Comment: @watashiSHUN I would have guessed that it wouldn't compile. But it does, and it works just as I described above.

Comment: a new feature? or are you using covariance? here is my error screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Ib0.png

Comment: @watashiSHUN The problem is that my example is way too narrow. It does compile for `Func<int, string>` but not for `Func<int, int>`. I'll have to get my head around that while I edit my answer.

Comment: You could - and I'm not recommending this - inspect the delegate you get back and get its second generic argument. Then use reflection to create a `MethodInfo` respresenting `MyFunction<T>` where `T` is the same type as your second generic argument. Then you can invoke that `MethodInfo` passing your `Func<int, ???>` as an argument.

Comment: hmm I just tested myself, the casting magic seems to only work for `Func`? in my actual code I am using a custom delegate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAqpw.png I guess it kind of make sense since when using self-declared delegate, compiler does not know about which Type argument is for return value and which is for parameter, hence it does not know about covariance and contravariance?

Comment: just to verify my theory: this works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSXSn.png and this fails as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mptu9.png